# Стандартный ввод и прерывания

Tags: c, unix

Пусть есть процесс со стандартным вводом с консоли. Процесс ждёт ввод данных.  Я ввожу какую то инфу и жму  enter.

Верна ли следующая последовательность действий?

1. Генерируется прерывание и инфа записанная в консоль пишется в файл, который ассоциирован с stdin
2. Потом(в процессе того же прерывания) обработчик прерывания пишет в адресное пространство процесса инфу из файла
3. Удаляет инфу из файла на файловой системе и возвращает управление

Comment: [How I/O channels are implemented in Linux kernel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96694)

Comment: What reasons for writing in Eng?)

Comment: Если сводить три вопроса к одному, то я хочу понять, каким путем попадает инфа в расположение процесса который ждёт

Comment: Это довольно сложный внутренний процесс ядра Linux, который описан по ссылке выше. Если вас конкретно интересует, сохраняется ли ввод предварительно на HDD, то нет - всё происходит в рамках виртуальной ФС, через внутренние буферы Linux. Ввод с клавиатуры попадает в буфер, который затем становится доступен процессу через `stdin`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо) не осознал сразу что то ссылка была)